# Weird cross platform support in ffmpeg

Tags: c, ffmpeg, linker, linker-errors

I tried to build ffmpeg `4.4` library and link with it and I received multiple unresolved references. I came across on unusual architecture in ffmpeg for multiple platforms.The library has many places with code like this:

```
void foo()
{
    // DO SOMETHING
    if (ARCH_MIPS) // maybe #if ARCH_MIPS (...) #endif should be used instead?
         foo_mips(...);
    if (ARCH_PPC)
        foo_ppc(c);
    if (ARCH_ARM)
         foo_arm(...);
    if (ARCH_AARCH64)
        foo_aarch64(...);
}
```

This code leads to linker errors because there is no any stub methods for other platforms. I observed root `MakeFile`, it optionally includes platform dependent code for each library (path like `$(LIB_SUBDIR)/$(ARCH)/MakeFile`) where each `foo_<arch>` is defined.

So, how does it work? In my opinion preprocessor directive `#if` should be used, otherwise we will receive unresolved reference on any platform. Maybe I missed something? because this code appears frequently for example:

1. `utils.c : ff_yuv2rgb_init_tables_ppc`
2. `swscale_unscaled.c : ff_get_unscaled_swscale_ppc, ff_get_unscaled_swscale_arm,` ff_get_unscaled_swscale_aarch64
3. `cpu.c : ff_get_cpu_max_align_x86, ff_get_cpu_max_align_mips`
4. `float_dsp.c : ff_float_dsp_init_aarch64, ff_float_dsp_init_ppc, ff_float_dsp_init_x86`
5. `etc.`

Comment: Did you try an optimizing compiler? It may well remove calls that follow a false conditional, so no such references are to be resolved.

Comment: @thebusybee It was first thing I thought about. But code also failed for compiler with enabled link time code generation and elimination of unused functions.